# problem: throwing exception in re.match function

Tags: python, regex, exception

I have one simple question about throwing exeptions in re.match function

Is there a way to 'match' function threw an exception? Maybe some flag. If this is not possible maybe there is some other function in RE library which throw an exception when the list will be empty for example.

Example:

```
verify_link=re.match(".*"+str(country).lower()+"."+str(city).lower()+".*",link)
```

This example in some cases returns None

I am looking for a method that would throw Exception, not None
I can do this by 'if' statement, but mayby there is any other way

Comment: could you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: I updated post, sorry for poor description, i wrote it in a hurry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such function(s) in Python `re` module.  See the [doc](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.error):

> exception re.error
>
> Exception raised when a string passed to one of the functions here is
>   not a valid regular expression (for
>   example, it might contain unmatched
>   parentheses) or when some other error
>   occurs during compilation or matching.
>   It is **never an error if a string
>   contains no match for a pattern.**

Answer (score 2):

```
if re.match(".*"+str(country).lower()+"."+str(city).lower()+".*", link) is None:
    raise Exception('whatever')
```

Answer (score 1):

Erm? Exceptions should happen only in exceptional situation, not the one you are describing. But, if you have to, you can always check return value using `if` and then raise exception.

Edit: and even make own function, to hide the exception throwing...

Comment: If you're expecting a match but there isn't one, that's exceptional.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to throw exception??? so you can use [index](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html?highlight=string.index#string.index) string method, for example:

```
verify_link = link.index(str(country).lower()+"."+str(city).lower())
```

EDITED: You should take into account that '.' will match dot only in my example above.

But i think that this is not the best way to check that sub-string is within string.

Comment: `.` will not have the same meaning here as in a regex.